# About lock on touch event in C#

Tags: c#, events, locking, volatile, raw-input

I use the rawinput to get touch events and want to do something only once when touching the screen. This is an example.

```
private volatile bool running = false;
    private object runLock = new object();
    private void OnTouchOnHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (runLock)
        {
            if (!running)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("1");
                running = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I will get several MessageBoxes when I touch the screen at first three or four times. That's really strange. Why lock and volatile variables dont work at first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely reason of the behavior that you have multiple instances of whatever object that contains `bool running` flag.

`lock` will prevent multiple threads from executing the same block of code. Most UI operations are executed on the same thread, so code will be allowed to re-enter the same block (`lock` is not doing anything when acquired multiple times on the same thread). In your case simple `bool` flag should be enough without using `lock`.

Comment: Thanks, I move the line "running = true;" to the beginning in the "if{}", and it works, without lock and volatile variable. I really confused about previous result, does it re-enter the handler without modifying the running flag? or why it works when I modify the order if there are multiple instances?

Comment: My guess MessageBox is semi-synchronous - it will not move the next line, but still let events to be handled. If it is true you should see with original code multiple calls to the `OnTouchOnHandler` on call stack.